# 'self' is not defined - threading with Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, timer, pyqt

My Code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    t = 59

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #...

        self.changeTxt()

    def changeTxt(self):        
        self.nxtUpdate.setProperty("value", self.t)
        self.t = self.t > 0 if self.t-1 else 59
        Timer(1, self.changeTxt).start()
```

**Error:**
`NameError: name 'self' is not defined` **, line:** `Timer(1, self.changeTxt).start()`

Why? and how can I fix it?

btw i'm using pyqt

Comment: Sounds like an indentation error. Run `python -tt` on your script to verify you didn't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: That's not the actual indentation you have in your code. Please update.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It was an indention problam!!! thanks you solved it, want to post it as an answer so i'll be able to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an indentation error. Run `python -tt` on your script to verify you didn't mix tabs and spaces.

Best practice is to only uses spaces or tabs, not mix the two. Most projects and certainly the [Python Style Guide PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommend you use spaces only.

Comment: Thanks, if you can please explain to me, why are spaces recommended while tabs are faster to input?

Comment: @DanBarzilay: You configure your editor to use spaces for indentation; then when you hit `TAB` spaces are inserted. Tab width is variable; it depends on whatever is reading and displaying the file on what width a tab is given, and that leads to confusion and debate.